# Delete @ mention from dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a little problem with deleting *just* the first mentions from a tweet. For exemple, I have this comment "@Marlappa @Sylard @Lau you are in @CoolCool bar" I want the comment to be "you are in @CoolCool bar". I managed to detect and print the first mentions from the comment column in my dataframe but when it come to delete them the code doesn't work.

I have this dataframe

```
import pandas as pd  
  
# exemple of dataframe  
data = {'social_Media': ['facebook', 'twitter', 'facebook', 'twitter', 'twitter'], 'comments': ['bla bla bla', '@Jane @Doe work in @office', '@Mark is the CEO', '@YoYo is @cool', 'XoXo YoYo']}  
dframe = pd.DataFrame(data)  

dframe['NEW_comments'] = '' #add new column of the new commet after deleting the @

print(dframe)
```

to print the @, I just do :

```
for i, j in enumerate(dframe['social_Media']):
  if j == "twitter":

    comment = dframe['comments'].iloc[i].split() # to a list
    for k in comment:
      if k[0] == "@" :
        print(k)
      else : break
```

this one will print the  @Jane, @Doe, @YoYo. but when I do this :

```
for i,j in enumerate(dframe['social_Media']):
  if j == "twitter":

    comment = dframe['comments'].iloc[i].split()
    for k in comment:
      if k[0] == "@" :
        comment.remove(k) 
      else : break
    dframe['NEW_comments'].iloc[i] = " ".join(comment)
  else : 
    dframe['NEW_comments'].iloc[i] = dframe['comments'].iloc[i] # if not a tweet leave the comment as it is
```

I just got different result :

```
social_Media                comments             NEW_comments
facebook                 bla bla bla              bla bla bla
twitter   @Jane @Doe work in @office     @Doe work in @office
facebook            @Mark is the CEO         @Mark is the CEO
twitter               @YoYo is @cool                       is
twitter                    XoXo YoYo                XoXo YoYo
```

it doesn't delete the 2d @ in the 2d comment and delete all the @ in the 4th comment :(

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: delete the mention from a tweet